# Retornando apenas um select por vez multiusuarios

Tags: banco-de-dados, sql-server, select

Tenho vários clientes conectados a um bando de dados.

Esses clientes fazem consultas, quase que ao mesmo tempo, me causando dor de cabeça, quando 2 clientes pegam o mesmo resultado de um select.

Como faço para saber quando uma tabela esta ocupada ou ate mesmo travar essa tabela ate que um cliente consulte para liberar ao outro, não quero perder o sentido de multiusuário, como ficaria esse consulta.

Comment: como assim, qual o problema que tem de dois cliente consultar a tabela ao mesmo tempo?

Comment: Olá @GustavoArantes! Seja bem vindo ao SOpt! Peço por gentileza, que leia os item [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) e [Central de Ajuda](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help) para que possamos lhe ajudar! Desde já agradecemos! Saudações,

Comment: Goku me desculpa me expressei mal, esqueci de mencionar que cada consulta retorna um numero ID, e para cada ID retorna em cada cliente, é feito uma edicao nesses dados, o que acontece, e que 2 clientes pegam esse mesmo ID e fazem a alteracao na tabela.

Comment: Alguma resposta ajudou a resolver o problema e pode sanar dúvidas similares de outros usuários? Caso positivo não esqueça de marcar a resposta como aceita. Pra fazer isso é só clicar no ✓ do lado esquerdo da mesma (abaixo do indicador de up e down votes).

Answer (score 3):

Gustavo, há uma diferença entre [multiusuário](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiusu%C3%A1rio) e [multitarefa](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitarefa). O sintoma que você relata nos comentários, "*2 clientes pegam esse mesmo ID*", provavelmente deve-se à [concorrência de processos](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concorr%C3%AAncia_(ci%C3%AAncia_da_computa%C3%A7%C3%A3o)) de um sistema multitarefa.

Você deve rever a programação para evitar que o mesmo ID seja fornecido a dois ou mais processos diferentes. Eis sugestão baseada no item “Automatic Handling of Sequence” do livro “Inside Microsoft SQL Server 2008: T-SQL Programming”, de Itzik Ben-Gan.

**1)** Crie uma tabela denominada Fornece_ID, em que ficará registrado o último valor de ID.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.Fornece_ID', 'U') is not null
  DROP TABLE dbo.Fornece_ID;
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.Fornece_ID (Valor int not null);
INSERT INTO dbo.Fornece_ID values (0);
```

**2)** Sempre que necessitar de obter um novo valor de ID, execute o seguinte trecho:

```
DECLARE @ID as int;
UPDATE dbo.Fornece_ID set @ID = Valor = Valor +1;
```

Na variável @ID é fornecido o novo valor de ID. Observe que é utilizado uma variante especial da instrução UPDATE.

Dependendo da aplicação e do contexto, pode implementar isto de forma transparente para a aplicação, através de procedimento *trigger*. Explicações detalhadas sobre este método estão disponíveis no livro indicado.

---

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que, pela explicação acima, o ideal é que você utilize a função `newid()` do SQLServer. Ela retornará pra você um hash único, evitando que dois usuários obtenham o mesmo identificador. Exemplo:

```
select newid() -- 77D704BE-B264-41F4-8C89-69886D5C60BE
```